# How to create a jar file

Tags: java, jar

There are no good tutorials about creating `JAR` file. I tried to create the `JAR` file and use it different projects. I can create a class without activity as the library with `className.java` format but I tried many times to create the `JAR` file`, but I can not. Please help me create a JAR file step by step.

Comment: Why don't you try using a `IDE`? NetBeans, Eclipse

Comment: You mean to tell me that [this didn't help?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)  Also, how does this relate to Android?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading basic [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/).

Basically it's done using the "jar" tool distributed with the JDK.

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

Once you are familiar with the concepts, you can use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ to easily create jar files. This is a tutorial on how to do it in [Eclipse](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_create_jar_files.htm).

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please update it with sufficient information.